# How to Troubleshoot 403 response from direct upload to s3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I'm having trouble getting a form to upload a file directly into an s3 bucket.

I'm using the [s3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) gem, which has a dependency on jquery fileupload.

I've setup the s3 bucket to have minimal restrictions, but for some reason I still keep getting a 403 response from AWS.

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId> <RANDOM STRING> </RequestId><HostId><RANDOM STRING></HostId></Error>
```

I've set up the most permissive CORS configuration possible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've granted "Everybody" permission to

- list
- update/delete
- view permissions
- edit permissions

At this point, I don't know how any request could be unauthorized, since the bucket is essentially configured to let anyone do anything.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utf8"

✓
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

uploads/1447269443856-xcjh25vu8up7gb9-69af20ec461f950cf3a980c9446396e3/${filename}

------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

public-read
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

<MY ACCESS KEY ID>
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMS0xMlQxOToxNzoxMloiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiR1dGY4IiwiIl0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRrZXkiLCJ1cGxvYWRzLyJdLFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCIkeC1yZXF1ZXN0ZWQtd2l0aCIsIiJdLFsiY29udGVudC1sZW5ndGgtcmFuZ2UiLDAsMTA0ODU3NjAwMF0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRjb250ZW50LXR5cGUiLCIiXSx7ImJ1Y2tldCI6InNvcnJpc28tZGV2In0seyJhY2wiOiJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fc3RhdHVzIjoiMjAxIn1dfQ==
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

KrHAZYBEL5zVrQuJSZpTdOZc2V4=
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

201
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="X-Requested-With"

xhr
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-type"

""
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"


------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content-type"

image/jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary0n0SgYfEpaal52hL--
```

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/bnd5k/352b7abde8d472f11872) containing the javascript that modifies the original form, in case that provides any clues.

The error message I receive from Amazon is pretty unhelpful.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I can get more info on what Amazon is expecting?

Comment: Silly question, but are your credentials set up properly in an intializer, like so:

S3DirectUpload.config do |c|
  c.access_key_id = ""       # your access key id
  c.secret_access_key = ""   # your secret access key
  c.bucket = ""              # your bucket name
  c.region = nil             # region prefix of your bucket url. This is _required_ for the non-default AWS region, eg. "s3-eu-west-1"
  c.url = nil                # S3 API endpoint (optional), eg. "https://#{c.bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/"
end

Comment: Even if your permissions are wide open, you'll still need proper aws credentials set up in the gem

Comment: Examine the form data from the request body again...  It doesn't make sense.  There are two `file` elements, one of them empty, and there is one `content-type` and one `Content-Type` element.  Also, this is not CORS related (fwiw).

Comment: Thanks!  You're comments got me to investigate the user's credentials, which were correct, but had no permission policy set.  Thanks!